# Protractor E2E Angular- Possible to test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to testing and recently just started using Protractor. I am kind of confused on how to approach this testing case. Lets say there are a bunch of buttons that when clicked will return an object with a set of properties unique depending button was clicked. The properties are then displayed somewhere. What I want to do is access this object that was returned and expect it's to match with what is displayed. Is it even possible to access this object?  Or should I be testing this somewhere else in a unit/integrated test? In an integrated test I would be able to access the component and the object returned.

Comment: Do you need additional explanation?

Comment: Nope, thank, I understand now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor is for UI/System testing: testing the *behavior* of your user interface and functionality of your system as a whole (thus end-to-end). What exactly happens behind the scenes is out of scope conceptually, even though it would be technically possible (using `browser.executeAsyncScript`). You should be testing your API responses with separate tests directly against your API and using unit tests (Mocha or similar) within your UI to ensure your UI logic parses expected API responses correctly.